# Комбинация директив для openmp

Tags: c++, openmp

К примеру у меня есть некий цикл для распаралеливания:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
  arr[i] += 5;   
}
```

При этом для правильного распаралеливания мне необходимо две директивы:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel // непосредственно для распаралеливания
#pragma omp for // для правильной работы с циклом
```

Есть вариант:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp for
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
    arr[i] += 5;   
  }
}
```

Но мне он не очень нравится, так как нужна дополнительная пара скобок. Можно ли сделать так?:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
  arr[i] += 5;   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете сделать даже так:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) 
  arr[i] += 5;
```

Comment: действительно, не знал о такой комбинации